# TensorFlow Keras guide: custom layer get_config method not updating the layer's configuration?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Under the [custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#custom_layers) section of the TensorFlow Keras guide there is an optional implementation of the `get_config` method:

```
  def get_config(self):
    base_config = super(MyLayer, self).get_config()
    base_config['output_dim'] = self.output_dim
```

Running the full code with some dummy data, then looking at the configuration produced by calling `model.get_config()` after `model.fit(...` yields the following output:

```
[{'class_name': 'MyLayer', 'config': None},
 {'class_name': 'Activation',
 'config': {'name': 'activation_38',
  'trainable': True,
  'dtype': 'float32',
  'activation': 'softmax'}}]
```

My question is: should the config for the custom layer 'MyLayer' not contain the `output_dim` field as as a result of the final assignment in the `get_config` method? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `get` method without a `return` statement?

That's the reason for `None`.

```
def get_config(self):
    base_config = super(MyLayer, self).get_config()
    base_config['output_dim'] = self.output_dim
    return base_config
```